# How do I fix flickering Webview in flyout upon flyout opening?

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I have an app that opens a flyout via custom user control. The flyout xaml contains a webview with content given to it via "[webview].NavigateToString()".

When the flyout opens, it does a slight sliding animation from just below the center of the screen to the center of the screen and loads the content (this is the default animation).

The webview content is loaded immediately and when the flyout is finished loading everything, the webview flickers.

I have tried all of the "on load" and "loaded" events to no avail. The flicker always happens after those events.

My only workaround is to set a dispatcher timer to make the webview visible once the flyout is completely finished loading and animating.

Does anyone know how to fix this without the timer?

Note: Upon close inspection on the client machine (surface pro 3), it seems as if the webview is reloading the css style for the webview. I can see the webview with the correct style, then the "flicker" is slow enough that I can see the styling disappearing for a split second then the styling is applied again. I tried removing the styling completely and there is still a flicker. Perhaps it is reloading the entire webview after the flyout is done loading?

Edit: Ok. I have confirmed that it has to do with the default flyout transition. In another area of my app, I use a webview as part of a page. I turned on a transition for that page and the webview did the exact same flicker! Therefore if I can remove the flyout transition completely, the flicker ***should*** disappear.

Edit #2: So far I am unable to remove the transitions from the flyout.

Comment: Flyout applies ContentTransitions to its ContentPresenter, I'd look at disabling that and see if you get the same result.

Comment: I am not able to disable them. I tried using a setter to set the transitions properties to be empty when setting the flyout style and it still did the animation.

Comment: Well I imagine you still want the animation for the actual flyout, but the content inside it also as the animation that I'm wondering is the culprit. I'll have to get a sec to go dig around it to see how to ditch it. I suppose if you wanted though you could also try slapping your webview into a tooltip template and get what you're after. I'm just not entirely sure why the webview content is behaving that way, it's a curiousity.

Comment: I tried putting the webview inside the tooltip and it still does the flicker.